# How to set uniqueness in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `1:N` model relationship between `User` and `Post` where as `post` model has following fields

```
name
is_deleted
```

## Model class for Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 validates_uniqueness_of :name
 ....
```

In above case when we will save the `Post.name` it should be `unique` in whole database. But according to my scenario I want to apply `Post.name` unique validation for each user.

Let's take a scenario:

```
user1 can have @post.name = `first` but it can't save the another post with the name of 'first'

user2 can still save the `post.name` = first
```

How can I implement that validation in `post` model

Answer (score 1):

Instead of validating the uniqueness of `:name`, you need to validate the uniqueness of `:name, :user_id`

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :user_id
```

(I just searched for how to do this in Rails. I don't know rails, only how databases work)

Apparently in rails 4:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

This is kind of dumb because honestly it should be symmetric, because you are just trying to create a uniqueness constraint on the model that is equivalent to saying that there is a compound key in the database `(:name, :user_id)`.